# error in taking input string after integer in java

Tags: java, string, int, java.util.scanner

I was trying to do this :

```
int n = myScanner.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   String str = myScanner.nextLine();
   .
   .
   .
}
```

when i compiled it shows some errors  java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117).
initially i thought it is a problem of nextLine() so i used next() . then i found out if i add  myScanner.nextLine() after taking input in n i.e

```
    int n = myScanner.nextInt();
    myScanner.nextLine();
```

Then it worked fine. I want to know why this happened?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods for the explanation.

Comment: @Codebender I visited the above link. In the solution,exception handling is done while using Integer.parseInt(), But when I used parseInt, it does not throw any exception. why is it so?

Comment: @hermit, a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown only if it cannot be parsed. But a `NumberFormatExcetion` is an **unchecked** (extending RuntimeException) exception, so you don't have to explicitely write throws or handle it (though it will be thrown up if you dont). Hope that's clear.

Comment: @Codebender I thought trying to parse the newline character into integer value would throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consume the newline character you enter when passing the integer:

```
int n = myScanner.nextInt(); //gets only integers, no newline
myScanner.nextLine(); //reads the newline
String str;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   str = myScanner.nextLine(); //reads the next input with newline
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a newline character left in the stream. Use the code by @moffeltje or probably try this:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(myScanner.nextLine());
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   String str = myScanner.nextLine();
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: You have to handle the NumberFormatException if you are going to use this method because the parseInt will try to parse the newline character into a integer value

Comment: @hermit, `Scanner.nextLine()` will **consume** the new line character, but it **wont** be returned to the caller. So the newline character is not going to be parsed.

Comment: From the Scanner java doc,  This method returns the rest of the current line, **excluding any line separator at the end**. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.